# How to use a few UIAlertView with a method

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I tried to make a several UIAlertView and called them- alert, alert1, alert2.
I used this method to determined which button was pressed:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex == 0 && alertView == alert){
//some code in here...
}
else if (buttonIndex == 0 && alertView == alert1){
//some code in here...
}
else if (buttonIndex == 0 && alertView == alert2){
//some code in here...
}
}
```

Problem is that Xcode throws "Use of undeclared identifier 'alert'", "Use of undeclared identifier 'alert1'", "Use of undeclared identifier 'alert2'".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can to use `tag` property of `UIAlertView` for this.

Use like -

Creting `UIAlertView` -

```
alertView.tag = 1;
```

In `clickedButtonAtIndex` method -

```
if (alertView.tag == 1) {
// Do task here 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like this:  'UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
**alert.tag = 1;**
    [alert show];'

Comment: Thanks! Marking as the answer.